# Create clickable map with all countries of the world in react native

Tags: react-native

I'd like to have a package that can create a clickable map of the world with all the countries in react native.

Answer (score -1):

It's the package which provides clickable map functionality

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-world-map

Comment: This component allows only to select continents, but selecting countries is desired.